# Storing user data in an object in local storage

Tags: javascript

I am doing a school project on creating a web site. I have managed to save user data into local storage upon signing up for an account. when I tried with the following codes yesterday, the codes could work: 
the key 'currentUser' would appear in the local storage after I have logged in as a user. However, after I cleared my local storage (too many users in array) and I re-run the codes again the currentUser would no longer show up in local storage. 
Here are my codes:
From edit profile page:
    `

```
<script>
var currentUser=null;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",loadUserData);

function loadUserData() {
currentUser = localStorage.getItem("currentUser");
if(currentUser!=null) {
currentUser = JSON.parse(currentUser);

    }
}
</script>
```

The above codes plus this from the login html shows the currentUser as the key in local Storage (should only appear upon logging in as current user)
From login page:

```
    function checkUser(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
          var status=false;

          var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
          var password = document.getElementById("password").value;


          for(var i=0;i<userList.length;i++) {
            var u=userList[i];
            console.log(u.username);
            console.log(u.password);
            if (u.username==username && u.password==password){
            status=true;
                            localStorage.setItem("currentUser",username);
            currentUser=userList[i];
            break;
            }
          }

          if (status==true){
            location.href="EditProfile.html";
          }

     }
```

What showed up in the local storage was just the key currentUser, but it's value is empty. I want the data info of the currentUser shown in local storage after the user has logged in, so that I can display the user details in the edit profile and profile page.

What I expected to see in local storage:

```
key             value
currentUser    {"username":"staff3","name":"stella ","password":"123","rpassword":"123,"email":"g@gmail.com"}
```

What showed in local storage:

```
key           value
currentUser    //nth showed up here
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the problem:

LocalStorage only store strings. If you want to store an object, you can use

```
 JSON.stringify(object)
```

So in your case, you need:

```
localStorage.setItem("currentUser",JSON.stringify(userList[i]));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey it worked! thank you so much! *feeling grateful*

Comment: erm I would like to display the object data from local storage into a textbox, I did this:document.getElementById('username').value = currentUser.username;
which worked previously, but now it didn't work> why is this so?

Comment: I am glad it helped. Consider picking it as your answer if it solved your problem

Comment: i added this line after the currentUser = JSON.parse(currentUser); line

Comment: when you get the data back from localstorage you need to use JSON.parse to get it back

Comment: hmmm would u mind leaving ur email here? i would like to send u my codes on what i had done . u can delete the comment w/ ur email after I've sent u

Answer (score 0):

simply do this

```
  function checkUser(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var status=false;

      var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
      var password = document.getElementById("password").value;


      for(var i=0;i<userList.length;i++) {
        var u=userList[i];
        console.log(u.username);
        console.log(u.password);
        if (u.username==username && u.password==password){
       console.log('Logged In');//check whether this console appears or not
                        localStorage.setItem("currentUser",userList[i]);//store whole data of logged user
        currentUser=userList[i];
        status=true;
        break;
        }
      }

      if (status==true){
        location.href="EditProfile.html";
      }

 }
```

Comment: Hello, I tried doing this, but it didn't work, the currentUser value showed:  [object Object]

Comment: shouldn't u be a string?

Comment: try to put userList[i]

Comment: localStorage.setItem("currentUser",userList[i]);

Comment: make sure your if statement evaluates to true, put a console.log statement in there to verify

Comment: check the console inside if loop